# Parse Data of a String in R

Tags: regex, r, string, parsing

I need help in solving what seems like a very easy problem. I have a string,`70 - 3/31/2014 - 60@1.66`. I would like to parse out only the information between the second "-" and before the "@", i.e "60". Is there any formula or nested formula in R that can parse out string data between two specified characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through sub,

```
> x <- "70 - 3/31/2014 - 60@1.66"
> sub("^[^-]*-[^-]*-\\s*([^@]*)@.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "60"
> sub("^[^-]*-[^-]*-([^@]*)@.*", "\\1", x)
[1] " 60"
> sub("^(?:[^-]*-){2}\\s*([^@]*)@.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "60"
```

- `^` - Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[^-]*-` Matches all the characters but not of `-`, zero or more times and the following hyphen.
- `(?:[^-]*-){2}` - And the above pattern would be repeated exactly two times. So we end up with the second hyphen.
- `\\s*` - Matches zero or more space characters.
- `([^@]*)` - Captures any character but not of `@` zero or more times.
- `.*` - Matches all the remaining characters.

So by replacing all the matched chars with the chars inside group index 1 will gave you the desired output.

**OR**

```
> x <- "70 - 3/31/2014 - 60@1.66"
> m <- regexpr("^(?:[^-]*-){2}\\s*\\K[^@]*(?=@)", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1] "60"
```

[`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

Comment: This works well. I find Grothendieck's answer easier to understand. But your bullet points were helpful in understanding and breaking apart the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**1) sub** This matches the entire string and then replaces it with the capture group, i.e. the portion matched to the part of the regular expression in parentheses:

```
x <- "70 - 3/31/2014 - 60@1.66"
sub(".*- (.*)@.*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "60"
```

and here is a visualization of the regular expression used:

```
.*- (.*)@.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-zexCnWRKRgnf5U4)

**2) gsub** This replaces the portion before the wanted substring and the portion after the wanted substring with empty strings:

```
gsub(".*- |@.*", "", x)
# [1] "60"
```

whose regular expression can be visualized as:

```
.*- |@.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kGnMcukPZ73wpeUN)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! You and Avinash helped a bunch!